# Отфильтровать уникальные значения, которых нет в массиве и занести их туда

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Есть массив с цифрами, есть функция в которую передается строчка с цифрами, нужно отфильтровать уникальные значения, которых нет в первом массиве и занести их туда.

Саму функцию я ее сделал, но хотелось бы задать вопрос касательно моего кода: есть ли возможность обойтись без цикла `for`, используя только методы массива?

Как-то можно реализовать эту задачу в одну краткую строку?

Заранее спасибо за ответ

```js
    let a = ["1", "4", "6"];
    
    let b = (str) => {
        let c = str.split('').filter(item => !a.includes(item))
    
        for(let d of c) {
            a.push(d)
        }
    }
    
    b("146987")
    
    console.log(a)
```

Comment: `let c = str.split('').filter(item => !a.includes(item)).map(item => a.push(item))`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, `a = a.concat(str.split('').filter(item => !a.includes(item)))`

Comment: @Grundy просвятите ламера, вызов map в данном случае неэффективен? (доку смотреть лень :) )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, как минимум создается лишний массив, который никак не используется. Лучше на forEach его заменить. Ну и добавлять по одному элементу и concat могут по разному работать в зависимости от внутренней реализации

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```js
const array = ["1", "4", "6"]
const string = "146987"

string.split("").forEach(item => { !array.includes(item) && array.push(item) })

console.log(array)
// [ "1", "4", "6", "9", "8", "7" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, за один проход. Добавить не достающие элементы (не изменяя исходный массив, уникальность элементов в котором не требовалось по условию задачи)

```js
let a = ["1", "4", "4", "6"];
    
"146987".split('').reduce((acc, item) => { if (!acc.unique.has(item)) { acc.unique.add(item); acc.result.push(item); } return  acc }, { unique: new Set(a), result: a});
    
console.log(a)
```

После беседы с Grundy переписал Array.includes на Set.has

Comment: за один проход по чему? :-)

Comment: @Grundy по входной строке в цикле. Идёт фильтрация и добавление в одном проходе

Comment: а includes по acc - ты не считаешь?

Comment: Это по сути фильтр. Избегать значит строить массив как нить по другому

Comment: не понял второе предложение.

Comment: Если не проверять на существование то нужно как-то изворачиваться

Comment: Ну так проверка, конкретно в текущем виде - это по сути второй цикл внутри первого. Ты можешь его улучшить за счет использования структуры типа объекта или Set тогда действительно можно считать что за один проход, так как проверка наличия ключа в объекте или в Set не зависит от длины последовательности

Comment: Согласен. Просто не использовал Set или подобие потому что это изменение начального массива на котором нет требование на уникальность

Comment: эм? причем тут изменение начального массива?тебе Set только внутри reduce нужно

Comment: Так асс инициализируется а

Comment: ну и что? :-) ты можешь чем угодно инициализировать, в том числе и объектом с несколькими полями, одним из которых может быть a

Comment: Ну вот смотри. Изначально [1,4,4,6] нужно добавить не хватающие из 12345. В редюсер скидываю 1,4,4,6 если из него делать сет то накроется это дело медным тазом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112311/discussion-between-grundy-and-aziz-umarov).

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала объединить, а потом фильтровать по уникальности

```
let a = ["1", "4", "6"];

let c = (str) => {
    a = a.concat(str.split('')).filter((v, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === i);
}

c("146987");

console.log(a);
```

Сравнение

```js
let a = ["1", "4", "6"];
let aa = ["1", "4", "6"];
    
let b = (str) => {
  let c = str.split('').filter(item => !a.includes(item))

  for(let d of c) {
    a.push(d)
  }
}

let c = (str) => {
    aa = aa.concat(str.split('')).filter((v, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === i);
}

b("146987");
c("146987");

console.log('b', a)
console.log('c', aa);
```

Comment: интересно что будет если дать на входе ["1", "4", "4", "6"]? В задаче не сказано на счет уникальности входного массива

Comment: @AzizUmarov, вы правы. Не учел. Но если вдруг он тоже должен быть уникальным, то ответ подойдет =)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = ["1", "4", "6"];
const log = console.log
let func = (str, arr) => [...new Set(str.split("").concat(arr))]

let b = func("146987", a)
let c = func("3", a)
let d = func("32432", a)

console.log(b, c, d)
```

Тоже поигрался маленько)

Comment: если используется `Set` то нет смысла дополнительного `filter`

Comment: Благодарю. Поправил

Comment: А что будет если `let a = ["1", "4", "4", "6"]`?

Comment: Тот же результат

Comment: Вероятно Вы проверяли

Comment: Это и без проверок ясно